# Difference between pings in same house?

Tags: connection, ping

My brother and I love to play league of legends however our pings vary greatly.

We are in the same room when my ping is around 100ms while his is 50ms.

I am using a Dell 15r and He is using a 2 year older mac book pro.

Any ideas why?

Comment: First - wired or wireless?  Second - does your ping times to your gateway differ or are they the same?  (Pinging usually to 192.168.1.1 or whatever your gateway is.)

Comment: How *precisely* are you measuring ping times?

Comment: I don't know that particular game, but ping times to a remote gaming server can vary also depending on how 'busy' each machine is in keeping up the constant connection, & the fps you are achieving relative to your max fps. In-game ping measurements can be very arbitrary. The real way to test the ping time is to find the location of the game server, using traceroute, then pingtest or speedtest to a point near to it, without the game running. It's possible that the server address itself may respond to pings, but it may not.